# Why is $\max\limits_b \|b\|_2 = \max\limits_b \|b\|_2^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I'm currently reading up some optimization theory. I've come across this equation (subject to some constraints):

$$\max_b \|b\|_2 = \max_b \|b\|_2^2$$

In this case, it is ensured that $\|b\| > 0$.
The authors say, that $x^2$ is a monotonic function for $x \geq 0$ and therefore the optimization problem is the same.
This sounds vaguely familiar, but I can't find more details or a proof why the solution is the same as of the squared function.

So far I understand, that a local minimum of a function is also a minimum of the squared function.
Let's assume my function $f$ has a local minimum at $\bar{x}$ and $f(\bar{x}) > 0$. It follows that $f'(\bar{x}) = 0$ and $f''(\bar{x}) > 0$

Let $z(x):=f^2(x)$ be the squared function of $f$.
$\Rightarrow z'(\bar{x}) = 2 f(\bar{x}) f'(\bar{x}) = 0$, because $f'(\bar{x}) = 0$
and $z''(\bar{x}) > 0 \Rightarrow z$ has a local minimum at $\bar{x}$.

But as far as I understand, it possible that $z$ has a local minimum at a point, where $f$ doesn't have a local minimum. Is that true? Unfortunately I can't think of an example right now.

My main question is:  Why is $\max\limits_b \|b\|_2 = \max\limits_b \|b\|_2^2$ ?

Comment: You are right to work with a general $f$. I suggest you look at optimization for convex functions. The function $x^2$ is convex. Study what happens when $f$ is or is not convex. As a counterexample, take $z(x)=\sin^2(x)$

Comment: Correction: replace "max" with "argmax".

Comment: You are probably asking either why $$\left(\max\limits_b\|b\|_2\right)^2 = \max\limits_b\|b\|_{2}^{2},$$ or why $$\arg\max\limits_b\|b\|_2 = \arg\max\limits_b\|b\|_{2}^{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\|b\|_2^2 = (\|b\|_2)^2$, we can ignore the fact that $b\in \mathbb R^n$ and just consider $x\in \mathbb R_+$, where $x = \|b\|_2$.

So the question is equivalent to proving that, given $S\subset \mathbb R_+$ (some subset of the set of nonnegative numbers) and $T = \{x^2 \mid x\in S\}$, to show that if $x = \max S$ then $x^2 = \max T$. (Because as Michael Grant points out, $x \neq x^2$.)

This is apparent from the monotonicity of the function $f(x) = x^2$ over $\mathbb R_+$.

Another way of looking at this is to observe that

$\log(\|b\|_2) = \frac{1}{2}\log(\|b\|_2^2)$

and since the RHS is log-concave, then so is the LHS, and it becomes apparent that $\|b\|_2$ is quasiconvex; that is, it is not convex but its local minima are also its global minima.